# What is wrong with this JSON string? Using Rails and ActiveSupport to decode

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

We're on Rails 3.0.6.

The following JSON string generates an **Invalid JSON String error** when we attempt to decode it in a controller with ActiveSupport::JSON. We cannot figure out what is generating the error, but we know it has something to do with the **draw_data_url** key.

```
"[{"draw_log":[[1,4,"width"],[2,"#000000","color"],[1,4,"width"],[5,[155,74],"move"],[3,[154,74],"line"],[3,[151,75],"line"],[3,[150,76],"line"],[3,[148,77],"line"],[3,[145,79],"line"],[3,[143,82],"line"],[3,[136,88],"line"],[3,[132,95],"line"],[3,[126,105],"line"],[3,[118,123],"line"],[3,[115,131],"line"],[3,[112,142],"line"],[3,[109,162],"line"],[3,[110,176],"line"],[3,[119,190],"line"],[3,[123,196],"line"],[3,[133,205],"line"],[3,[149,215],"line"],[3,[154,216],"line"],[3,[169,216],"line"],[3,[194,210],"line"],[3,[204,206],"line"],[3,[240,182],"line"],[3,[255,166],"line"],[3,[258,157],"line"],[3,[262,122],"line"],[3,[260,108],"line"],[3,[258,101],"line"],[3,[249,82],"line"],[3,[241,74],"line"],[3,[223,63],"line"],[3,[209,57],"line"],[3,[200,55],"line"],[3,[192,53],"line"],[3,[140,53],"line"],[3,[130,56],"line"],[3,[102,72],"line"],[3,[82,89],"line"],[3,[75,96],"line"],[3,[59,115],"line"],[3,[49,132],"line"],[3,[42,150],"line"],[3,[40,157],"line"],[3,[39,175],"line"],[3,[39,196],"line"],[3,[40,203],"line"],[3,[44,217],"line"],[3,[49,226],"line"],[3,[51,229],"line"],[3,[54,232],"line"],[3,[63,241],"line"],[3,[63,242],"line"],[3,[71,250],"line"],[3,[89,257],"line"],[3,[97,262],"line"],[3,[151,268],"line"],[3,[161,269],"line"],[3,[177,268],"line"],[3,[214,256],"line"],[3,[219,254],"line"],[3,[225,250],"line"],[3,[244,232],"line"],[3,[249,225],"line"],[3,[257,205],"line"],[3,[260,191],"line"],[3,[260,183],"line"],[3,[259,154],"line"],[3,[256,140],"line"],[3,[249,124],"line"],[3,[235,97],"line"],[3,[224,85],"line"],[3,[217,79],"line"],[3,[194,60],"line"],[3,[178,54],"line"],[3,[151,44],"line"],[3,[129,42],"line"],[3,[126,41],"line"],[3,[109,42],"line"],[3,[101,45],"line"],[3,[97,47],"line"],[3,[86,56],"line"],[3,[80,65],"line"],[3,[75,72],"line"],[3,[62,89],"line"],[3,[59,97],"line"],[3,[55,107],"line"],[3,[49,127],"line"],[3,[49,131],"line"],[3,[49,152],"line"],[3,[52,164],"line"],[3,[57,176],"line"],[3,[63,191],"line"],[3,[72,203],"line"],[3,[77,207],"line"],[3,[93,215],"line"],[3,[105,216],"line"],[3,[125,217],"line"],[3,[143,211],"line"],[3,[154,208],"line"],[3,[201,193],"line"],[3,[221,185],"line"],[3,[263,154],"line"],[3,[269,143],"line"],[3,[272,136],"line"],[3,[273,123],"line"],[3,[274,112],"line"],[3,[274,100],"line"],[3,[271,88],"line"],[3,[268,77],"line"],[3,[266,69],"line"],[3,[260,59],"line"],[3,[256,51],"line"],[3,[252,45],"line"],[3,[236,31],"line"],[3,[229,25],"line"],[3,[224,22],"line"],[3,[207,15],"line"],[3,[197,11],"line"],[3,[178,6],"line"],[3,[167,3],"line"],[3,[161,2],"line"],[3,[156,2],"line"],[3,[143,2],"line"],[3,[133,2],"line"],[3,[111,6],"line"],[3,[89,14],"line"],[3,[83,17],"line"],[3,[67,27],"line"],[3,[57,34],"line"],[3,[48,41],"line"],[3,[33,55],"line"],[3,[28,61],"line"],[3,[25,68],"line"],[3,[21,87],"line"],[3,[19,98],"line"],[3,[18,119],"line"],[3,[19,133],"line"],[3,[20,144],"line"],[3,[35,176],"line"],[3,[48,195],"line"],[3,[69,217],"line"],[3,[83,225],"line"],[3,[91,230],"line"],[3,[105,233],"line"],[3,[111,234],"line"],[3,[119,234],"line"],[3,[131,234],"line"],[3,[135,234],"line"],[3,[139,233],"line"]],"word":"RUN","draw_data_url":"data: image/png;base64,
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","guesses":{"4f6a20238cb45b16c00002a8":null},"turn_num":1,"word_value":null,"drawer_id":"4f68ed4b8cb45b16c0000111","value":2}]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://jsonlint.com/

The line break after `base64,` is not valid there (ignoring trailing and leading quotation marks):

```
Parse error on line 1221:
...   "draw_data_url": "data: image/png;bas
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

If you want to have a literal line break inside the string, you have to escape it as `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for this! We looked at the text and couldn't pinpoint the problem .... no wonder, it was a line break! Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, the value for "draw_data_url" is coming from canvas.toDataURL(). Are we doing something wrong if it's inserting line breaks? Also, if the line break isn't already represented in the string as "\n," which character are we supposed to search for and replace with "\n"? Sorry if these are stupid questions.

Comment: Check also for `\r`. Or remove/replace all white spaces with `/\s+/g`.... I think those URLs are not required to have spaces anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Felix ... a little confused when you say check also for "\n" since I thought we're supposed to replace the line breaks with "\n," suggesting the line breaks are represented by something other than "\n"?

Comment: Sorry :D I meant `\r` (got it confused in my head ;))... corrected.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) gives :

```
Parse error on line 1:
"[    {        "dr
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jsonlint.com it detected a line break in draw_data_url value

Once it was removed it validates fine:

Comment: Do you know how we can programmatically remove the line break? The value comes directly from canvas.toDataURL(). Are we doing something wrong if it's inserting line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

JSON format is key/value.

```
{"key": value, "key2": value}
```

Your first (weird) key doesn't seem to have a value.